# How to Open browser window on uninstall of a clickonce app

Tags: clickonce, uninstallation

i am deploying my app via clickonce.

I would like upon uninstall of the application, 
the popup a custom url. Is it possible?

(...and invite the user to take a pool for the reason of uninstall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible because the ClickOnce installation/uninstallation process is handled automatically. I don't think they have a way to extend that.

One slightly ugly way to accomplish this would be to provide your own bootstrapped MSI and have your ClickOnce deployment require that as a prerequisite. Then you'd have 2 apps show up installed, your prereq MSI and the actual ClickOnce app.